# does coalesce(1) the dataframe before write have any impact on performance?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hdfs, parquet

Before I write dataframe into hdfs, I `coalesce(1)` to make it write only one file, so it is easily to handle thing manually when copying thing around, get from hdfs, ...

I would code like this to write output.

```
outputData.coalesce(1).write.parquet(outputPath)
```

(outputData is  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)

I would like to ask if their are any impact on performance vs not coalesce

```
outputData.write.parquet(outputPath)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it will write with 1 worker.

So, even through you give 10 CPU core, it will write with 1 worker (single partition).

Problem if your file very big (10 gb or more). But recommend if you have small file (100 mb)

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend doing that. The whole purpose of distributed computing is to have data and processing sitting on multiple machine and capitalize the benefits of CPU/Memory of many machines (worker nodes).

In your case, you are trying to put everything in one place. Why do you need a distributed file system if you want to write into a single file with just one partition? Performance can be an issue but it can be only assessed after you check before/after using Coalesce function on huge amount of data that is spread across multiple nodes on cluster.

Comment: As long as you're operating purely within Spark, I'd agree. But sometimes you have to get data out of the Spark cluster and put it somewhere that uses a more conventional file system.

Answer (score 2):

Though really not suggested when dealing with huge data, Using coalesce(1) can be handy when there are too many small partition files in the _temporary and the file movement is taking quite a bit of time to move them into the proper directories.